# Best way to swap mouse buttons from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, mouse

I just wanted a clarification on the methods to do this, but I don't have "50 reputation," so I have to ask it as a new question:

I want to create a systemd job to swap mouse buttons. The comments suggest that using xinput is "better" than using xmodmap. Is the xinput id number assigned to a USB mouse independent of the USB port that I plug it into? If not, it seems like it would be better to use xmodmap. (I move this computer from room to room periodically, and don't want to remember which USB cable goes where.) Thanks.

Comment: Err... you do now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add links to those comments. Also, please read [ask] because your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to know how to swap mouse buttons? Do you want to know how to create a systemd service unit? Do you want to know if xinput id is independent from the USB port? And what about terminal?